# Create UIbuttons at a certain distance between them

Tags: objective-c, loops, uibutton, frame, distance

I made an app which has got API support for developers. Developer who want to make a plugin for my app just have to call a method " -(void)createToggle " and an UIButton will be automatically added to my application's view. The problem is that I don't know how to implement in " -(void)createToggle " a way to make UIButtons with a certain distance (180 in this case) between them.

I made a loop to do that, here you can see the code:

```
-(void)createToggle 
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<[[SPUtils dylibs] count]; i++) 
    {

        toggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        toggle.frame = CGRectMake(3487+180 *i, 27, 100, 100); 
        [toggle addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTarget:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [toggleScroll addSubview:toggle];

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the difference is between the code you posted and what you actually want.

Comment: yes this code shows what you need it works perfectly as you want in this question

Answer (score 0):

You could paste the snippet here. The problem seems to be on line:

```
toggle.frame = CGRectMake(3487+180 *i, 27, 100, 100);
```

3487 is a big number. Where the buttons are going to be placed? iPhone has a horizontal range of 0->320 for x.
Try this instead:

```
float margin=180;
float buttonWidth=100;
toggle.frame = CGRectMake(margin+i*buttonWidth+i*margin, 27, 100, 100);
```

Let me know if it's solved.

Comment: good one this is definitely solve the problem if so just accept it

Comment: It's for iPad and it's a scrollview.

Comment: then just replace the first `margin` in `CGRectMake(margin+....)` with your 3487. But still I'm confused with this huge number. Are you sure what you are trying to do? Please explain a bit in case you need more help. What sort of problems are you facing, what things seem to be awkward...anything...so that we might help. And don't forget to upvote and accept any answer if you get help from it ;)

Comment: Tell us explaining a bit what you are expecting to show in the screen, give something in details so that we may think of the algorithm.It's not that tough I guess. If you really need help you need to write a bit more than **'Doesn't Work'**. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. It still show buttons with the same frame. When -(void)createToggle is called, I need to make a button with 180 of distance between the button which precedes it. Have you go any idea on how to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: Then try the code I had given before. In my answer the first button will start with a margin of 180 and the 2nd one also keeping the same margin with the previous and then the 3rd one and will go on for each and every button you add. Make sure that your content area of the scrollbar is set to enough space.